# The jquery ui box to call inside div

Tags: jquery

```
    function getvoucher(id){
    $.get("http://inactive/test.php?id=" + id, function(data,status){
        return data;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        alert("alert");
        $("#popup").empty();
        var vid = $(this).attr("voucherid");
        var content = getvoucher(vid);
        //
        $("#popup").dialog();
    });
});
```

I have this to show my dialog box but I need to add in the popup div

```
<div id="popup">
</div>
```

The popup dialog to display the getvoucher(id), but I cant seem to figure out how, any help?

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Did you properly include jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 And I checked it but on that line is only <script>

Comment: As you mentioned its a syntax error, can you please provide complete code like which element has id as "opener" and what you are putting into the div#popup..

Comment: this is my whole code, but my problem is with $.get("http://inactive/test.php?id=" + id, function(data,status){

Comment: Am i witting in a wrong format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put div id, you can just call it through another file

Comment: Yeah I kinda figured.